# How can I get colored output of `systemd` commands run with `watch` inside xterm?

Tags: systemd, x11, wayland, xterm, watch

Somehow I'm unable to get this working with color output, it works but no colors are shown.

---

1. I'm currently using these `alias`'es in my `bash` shell:

   ```bash
   alias Xterm='xterm -geometry 132x60 +dc +cm -e '
   alias Watch='watch --color --differences --interval=1 --exec '
   alias xterm-watch='Xterm Watch '
   alias _nc='networkctl'
   alias nc-status='_nc --no-pager --stats --full status'
   alias nc-status-watch='xterm-watch nc-status'
   ```
2. `$TERM` is set to `xterm-256color`
3. When i enter `nc-status-watch` at the bash prompt, an `xterm` window pops-up correctly with a `watch` command running the `networkctl` command with it's arguments.
   But the output does not show any colors.

[image: Result of nc-status-watch]

How can I get colored output of `systemd` commands run with `watch` inside xterm?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1042175/how-do-i-get-systemctl-to-print-in-color-when-being-interacted-with-from-a-non-t

Comment: Thanks for the link which gave me the missing info ❤️ ( to self, upvote that answer when you reach enough rep)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @muru, I finally got colored output.

I needed this change:

```bash
alias Xterm='SYSTEMD_COLORS=1 xterm -geometry 132x60 -e '
```

- For `Wayland` i also needed `-rv` before the `-e` option to **reverse** the `fg/bg` colors used by `xterm`.
  This is unrelated to the current topic though...
  *Maybe a bug w.r.t. Wayland+xterm at moment?*

Reference: [How do I get systemctl to print in color when being interacted with from a non-tty?](https://superuser.com/q/1042175)

[image: Result of nc-status-watch with color]

Comment: To see my usage in action: https://gitlab.com/trimoon-inc/aliases/-/blob/main/shell_aliases.d/xterm-watch?ref_type=heads